# Play Framework - Schedule a task at precise time

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm doing a Scala - Play application and I want to schedule a task to sending mail everyday at 3 A.M, so I create a class for that but i'ts not working:

```
class ManageSendInvalidateDaemon @Inject() (app: Application, emailSender: EmailSender, mailer: MailerClient) {
    Akka.system(app).scheduler.schedule(
    scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.create(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.create(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    new Runnable(){
      override def run()={ 
         //Function to send the mail 
      }
   }
  );
};
```

I think the problem is here:

```
    scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.create(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.create(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
```

I don't really understand what it's the use of these 2 lines

Comment: You can use java schedulers or quartz . Quartz is preferable as it provide nice and simple API for this.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul The link from that answer points to Play 1.x documentation. That will work also with Play 2.x?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I just remembered seeing the linked question yesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will not work as you expect. Akka scheduler just lets you specify the recurrency of the task, but not the day, hour etc when it will run (ex: you can tell it to run a task every 10 minutes, but not run this at 15:30 each Monday).

Those two lines instruct Akka to run that task every 60 seconds, and run the first time 20 seconds after you define it (so if the `schedule` call is executed at 12h30m that task will run the first time at 12:30:20 and then 12:31:20, 12:32:20, etc).

To overcome this, you just need to run a task periodically (in your case, each minute for example), and check the current hour. If it is 3AM send those emails (and eventually store anywere that this task was executed).

Another option is to use something like [akka-quartz-scheduler](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler), that lets you specify that type of scheduling

Comment: Play! has support for this. See the suggested duplicate I linked to

Comment: @Clement.Cvl Try to inject `system: ActorSystem` in the constructor and then use it as `system.scheduler.schedule`

Comment: How can I adapt my code with the akka-quartz-scheduler ? Do you have any example which looks like my case ?

Comment: @Clement.Cvl No, sorry. There is an example named "Every30Seconds" in that GitHub repo that may help you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. So I created a method to calculate how much time from now until the time I want to run my

```
schedule = Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
               Duration.create(nextRunTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
               Duration.create(DAY_IN_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
               ...,);
```

The nextRunTime() method calculates how much time in milliseconds will be until the next 3 AM and after that I set an interval of one day (DAY_IN_MS)

```
private int nextRunTime() {
  String runTimeValue = "03:00";
  LocalTime now = new LocalTime();
  LocalTime runTime = new LocalTime(runTimeValue);
  int timeUntilRun;
  if (runTime.isAfter(now)) { // From now until the run time
    timeUntilRun = runTime.getMillisOfDay() - now.getMillisOfDay();
  } else { // From now until midnight, plus from midnight until the run time
    timeUntilRun = DAY_IN_MS - now.getMillisOfDay() + runTime.getMillisOfDay();
  }
  Logger.info("nextRunTime(): next run in " + timeUntilRun + " ms");
  return timeUntilRun;
}
```